# Are the terms of LGPL 3.0 already covered by GPL 3.0 aggregate definition

Tags: gpl, gpl-3, lgpl

Are full terms of [LGPLv3.0](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0.txt) already covered by [GPLv3.0](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt) section 5 under the terms of an "aggregate"?

> A compilation of a covered work with other separate and independent
>   works, which are not by their nature extensions of the covered work,
>   and which are not combined with it such as to form a larger program,
>   in or on a volume of a storage or distribution medium, is called an
>   "aggregate" if the compilation and its resulting copyright are not
>   used to limit the access or legal rights of the compilation's users
>   beyond what the individual works permit.  Inclusion of a covered work
>   in an aggregate does not cause this License to apply to the other
>   parts of the aggregate.

as far as i can tell, doesn't this cover the terms of the LGPL?

what is the point of the LGPL?

Answer (score 5):

Consider a library, let's call it `libfoo`, which you receive under GPLv3.  If you write code that links to `libfoo`, the position of the FSF is that the resulting executable, the combined work, is a derivative work of `libfoo`.  Under GPLv3 section 5c, if you convey this work to anyone else, you must license *the entire work* under GPLv3 - your code as well as `libfoo`'s.

Now consider a library, `libbar`, which you receive under LGPLv3.  If you write code that links to `libbar`, and you convey the resulting executable to others, then although you have several obligations with respect to `libbar` under LGPL, you are *not* obliged to license the combined work under GPL, and you may keep your code secret should you choose to.

That's the difference, and the point of LGPL.

The passage you quote above would not apply to such a work.  Firstly, because it does not use *compilation* in the sense of *a thing a compiler produces* but in the sense of *mix tape* - a collection of unrelated works on a single medium, such as a GNU/Linux distro DVD containing many different pieces of software covered by many different licences.  Secondly, what you quote above only applies to

> a compilation of a covered work with other [...] works, which are not by their nature extensions of the covered work, and which are not combined with it such as to form a larger program

An executable resulting from linking your code to `libfoo` fails that second test on its face, and (under the FSF's interpretation of linking) the first test also.

Comment: so could i link a closed source project to a GPLv3 library if i also linked to an unrelated BSD library(dynamically of course)?

Comment: No.  Why would you think that?

Comment: the BSD lib would make it an aggregate? would it not? i must be missing something?

Comment: I suppose i see what you are saying. my app itself is not part of the aggregate?

Comment: No.  Neither library makes the work an aggregate or otherwise; it is *copyright law* that determines if a newer work is a derivative of an earlier one.  The FSF's interpretation is that linking your code to pre-existing libraries makes your work a derivative of all those earlier works (the libraries), and if you wish to distribute the resulting executable, you must abide by the conditions placed upon you by *all* the earlier works in order to earn the right to distribute your newer work.

Comment: I still think theres got to be an easier way to word all this. Thank you!

Comment: To word all what?  Are you trying to ask what the aggregate language that you quote above really means?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54130/discussion-between-madhatter-and-kipbits).

Answer (score 4):

Using natively compiled applications in Linux and Windows as example, two program executables sitting on the same storage medium and interacting with each other only through inter-process communication methods like TCP/ UDP or Unix domain sockets or pipes, or protocols on top of these, like DBUS or DDS or MQTT, can be, for most cases, considered to be aggregates. Aggregates are not combined work.

Meanwhile, any form of dynamic (SO, DLL) or static linking  of an application to an independent library (which is not a standalone executable), where the application programmatically depends on the library but the library does not depend on the application, can be considered the case of combined work where the application is linked to a library.

The GPLv3's copyleft licensing conditions apply to the case of combined work above (with the special exception of system libraries), but it does not apply to the case of aggregates.

Meanwhile LGPLv3's copyleft licensing conditions applies only to the library and all its linked dependencies, but it does not apply to applications that use that library. It also does not apply to aggregates. However, it does have conditions towards the combined work, i.e. the recipient of the software must be able to modify the LGPLv3-licensed library and relink it to the application and install it.